# How can I get time.Time in Golang protobuf v3 struct?

Tags: mysql, go, timestamp, protocol-buffers

I'm using the google time package `github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes/timestamp` in protobuf message file  now.

```
google.protobuf.Timestamp UpdateTime = 9;
```

But the `UpdateTime` property becomes a pointer `*timestamp.Timestamp` in golang struct after protoc compiling, it's not a `time.Time` and I can't save these property into Mysql timestamp column.

What can I do?

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: ptypes already have convenient functions which convert between time.Time and *timestamp.Timestamp. [
https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes#Timestamp](http://%20https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes#Timestamp) [https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes#TimestampProto](https://godoc.org/github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes#TimestampProto)

Comment: import "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes"

createdObject,err := ptypes.TimestampProto(dbresponse[i].CreatedOn)
            if err !=nil{
                          log.Println("Error found:",err)
            }

Answer (score 41):

To obtain a `time.Time` from a protobuf field of type `google.protobuf.Timestamp`, use the [`AsTime` method](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb#Timestamp.AsTime) defined on the `timestamppb.Timestamp` type.

When producing the insert call into your database, or any other location where a `time.Time` is required, call `myMsg.UpdateTime.AsTime()` to obtain the required value (where `myMsg` is a variable to an instance of the relevant Protobuf message type).

---

This answer assumes you are using the new Protobuf APIv2 interface, defined in the `google.golang.org/protobuf` package, or that you are using the APIv2-compatible implementation of APIv1, defined in package `github.com/golang/protobuf` at version `v1.20` or greater.

Many projects are still to update to these versions. It is highly recommended that you look to upgrade your code generation and toolchain to benefit from new functionality.

Comment: So it need a process to convert the attribute format?

Comment: can protobuf define the attribute ``time.Time`` type in message?

Comment: In short, yes. A protobuf timestamp has no timezone info. Go's time.Time does. So one would need to add zoneinfo to any message alongside the timestamp. However, since protobuf is mainly used with micro-services & not usually user-facing, maintaining zoneinfo at a micro-service level is most likely not needed.

Comment: This answer is outdated. The function is deprecated.

Comment: @TehSphinX thanks, updated the answer to refer to APIv2 approach.

Answer (score 6):

The [AsTime](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb#Timestamp.AsTime) method can be used to convert a Timestamp message to a standard Go time.Time value in UTC:

```
t := ts.AsTime()
... // make use of t as a time.Time
```

The AsTime method performs the conversion on a best-effort basis. Timestamps with denormal values (e.g., nanoseconds beyond 0 and 99999999, inclusive) are normalized during the conversion to a time.Time. To manually check for invalid Timestamps per the documented limitations in timestamp.proto, additionally call the CheckValid method:

```
if err := ts.CheckValid(); err != nil {
    ... // handle error
}
```

This is documented in [timestamppb](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/timestamppb) package.